# Handling Device Rotation

Tags: android

I want to disable the view change on device rotation for the time being. Its giving foreclose error when i rotate the device and starts all over again.

I have used tab activity everywhere.

How should i proceed ?

Comment: Please note that you should at least handle config changes to a level where it doesn't crash :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your manifest, you can define which activities you don't want to rotate automatically by setting i.e.

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add this on your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/activity_label"/>
```

Ger

Answer (score 1):

What you need to set is set the [configChanges](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) attribute of the activity in your manifest. This will still allow the user to rotate the 'phone, but tells Android not to restart your activity when it does so.